# Directives in object created during app lifetime doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've created some basic directive. It works well if I use it with some objects in html file

```
<some-directive some-data="123"></some-directive>
```

But if I dynamically load this object to my webpage:

```
//getting html source as a string, then appending it to DOM:
elem.html("<some-directive some-data='123'></some-directive>");
```

The directive doesn't work (object is being added properly to DOM)

```
app.directive('someDirective', function (notes, parts) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {
        someData: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        console.log("directive fired");
    }
};
});
```

What can I do to make it work properly?

Comment: won't work without using `$compile` ... if you inject it yourself angular doesn't know it's there to do the compiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic directives, you have to use `$compile` service that compiles scope into template. Look at sample below, `<some-directive-wrapper />` will add `<some-directive />` element into itself and compile scope value

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('someDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            someData: '='
        },
        template: '<h2>someDirective compiled, someData is {{someData}}</h2>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            console.log("directive fired");
        }
    };
});
app.directive('someDirectiveWrapper', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
          
          //get value from ajax maybe
          //and set to scope
          scope.data = 123;

          //replace directive with another directive
          elem.html('<h1>someDirectiveWrapper compiled </h1>\n<some-directive some-data="data"></some-directive>');

          //compile scope value into template
          $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <some-directive-wrapper></some-directive-wrapper>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems like this html updates its angular "{{variables}}" only when I click on it. If I doesn't focus on object created that way, it doesn't update its view (scripts are working correctly, I used setInterval to check it)

Comment: do you know how to fix it?

Comment: I suggest you to open a new issue as it might be totally different case study